# Android How to record video using CWAC Camera library

Tags: android, android-camera, video-recording

I use following code for record video but recorded video file is not save or store in sdcard and can i record video in portrait mode.i got this code from link https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera

```
           if (!isRecording()) {
                try {
                    record();
                    getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(),
                            "Exception trying to record", e);
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), e.getMessage(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } else {
                try {
                    stopRecording();
                    getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(),
                            "Exception trying to stop recording", e);
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), e.getMessage(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
```

Comment: That library has been discontinued for quite some time. Please do not use it.

Comment: Hiii @CommonsWare please suggest me valid library for record video using custom camera.